# Where did Dr. Doom find the women who became Volcana and Titania?

Tags: marvel, comics, secret-wars, dr-doom

In [*Secret Wars* #3](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_3), Dr. Doom uses his newly found base (which he dubs the “Doombase”) to give superpowers to two women he’s apparently found. They later decide to take the names Volcana and Titania.

[image]

Where did Dr. Doom find these women? This panel is the first we see of them and last time we saw Dr. Doom, he was alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the start of *Secret Wars #7*, a bunch of the Marvel heroes bump into a costumed woman whom *none* of them have ever seen or heard of before: The second "Spider-Woman." (Her real name was later established to be "Julia Carpenter" -- all that Spidey and the Avengers and the Fantastic Four could see at a glance was that she definitely was **not** Jessica Drew, who had formerly starred in her own Marvel title for 50 issues as the *original* "Spider-Woman.")

When they realized this costumed lady spoke fluent English, and must be from Earth, Reed Richards said to her: "The Beyonder used fragments of many planets to build this world -- I assume you were **on** one of them!"

Spider-Woman said: "A whole suburb of Denver! We just suddenly found ourselves here!"

So we were halfway through the 12-part series before the good guys realized that the heroes and the villains who were all gathered together in the opening scene of *Secret Wars #1* were not the *only* people from Earth who were now stuck on this newly-assembled "Battleworld." That suburb of Denver probably had, at the very least, thousands (if not tens of thousands) of other human beings.

But it appears that Doctor Doom had somehow caught on to the presence of that suburb, somewhere many miles away from where the heroes were teleported down to Battleworld, much sooner than any of the heroes did. And he somehow recruited a couple of young women from that suburb who were both willing to be his voluntary guinea pigs in exchange for his promise that **if** his experiment worked the way he wanted it to, they would both become *incredibly* powerful. (Which is exactly what happened. We have to admit that Doom is a man of his word!)

We simply didn't *see* his little "recruiting speech" that somehow persuaded them to join forces with him for the time being. I guess Jim Shooter (the writer) was trying to be cagey, instead of just letting us know everything that Doctor Doom had already discovered about the peculiarities of this new world and its transplanted residents from various other places in the universe.